# How to use select case into in mysql

Tags: mysql

The following is the MSSQL syntax, how to convert this into mysql

```
    SELECT          
    _nextBillingDate = UB.NextBillingDate,
    _billingFrequency = (CASE IFNULL(UB.BillingFrequency,0) WHEN 0 THEN
     _defaultBillingFrequency ELSE UB.BillingFrequency END),
    _isCompletelyCreditBilled = (CASE WHEN PO.ChargeAmount > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    _ownerId = PO.OwnerId   
    FROM PaymentOrder PO
    INNER JOIN UserBillingInfo UB ON PO.OwnerId = UB.OwnerId
    WHERE PO.Id = _paymentOrderId
```

Comment: Read some about differences between MSSQL and MySQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: You can download applications available to convert from MSSQL to MySQL statements. Check it [one](http://www.convert-in.com/mss2sql.htm) [two](https://a5-downloads.phpnuke.org/en/c150357/mssql-to-mysql-database-converter-free-download-full-review)

Answer (score 2):

Within procedures, mysql uses the `select cols into vars from ...` style syntax, so try this:

```
-- DECLARE variables at the top of your procedure

SELECT
    UB.NextBillingDate,
    CASE IFNULL(UB.BillingFrequency,0) WHEN 0 THEN _defaultBillingFrequency ELSE UB.BillingFrequency END,
    CASE WHEN PO.ChargeAmount > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    PO.OwnerId
INTO
    _nextBillingDate, _billingFrequency, _isCompletelyCreditBilled, _ownerId 
FROM PaymentOrder PO
INNER JOIN UserBillingInfo UB ON PO.OwnerId = UB.OwnerId
WHERE PO.Id = _paymentOrderId
```

Comment: "select * into" in mysql
"select * into" is not allowed in mysql. Here is an example to get around this limitation:

CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable

Answer (score 0):

"select * into" in mysql
"select * into" is not allowed in mysql. Here is an example to get around this limitation:

CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable